# Which is faster, if inside a loop, or a just the loop?

Tags: performance

I am trying to understand some concepts of performance in code.

If there is, for instance, a 2d boolean array with 5 trues inside it,

if we want to change all the elements in the array to false, which code would be faster?

number1:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

number2:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j])        
            arr[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is the general rule that if you want to know the performance of specific implementations, you need to measure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can measure it by using `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()`:

Number 1:

```
    console.time('loop');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    console.timeEnd('loop');
```

loop: 0.046142578125ms

Number 2:

```
    console.time('loop');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j])
            arr[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    console.timeEnd('loop');
```

loop: 0.031982421875ms

The array I used was arr[1][135] big and had 5 values in the second array that were true.

As you can see the loop with the if clause is faster.